# how to create tag synonym in SharePoint forum

Tags: support

I want to create tag synonym in sharepoint forum. But i could not find a way to create or submit it.
i want 
PowerPoint Automation Services
Visio Graphics Service
Machine Translation Service

Comment: I must be missing something - that should be the synonyms for what? Could you please edit to specify the original tag and the synonym (sorry, maybe it is just me don't getting what you mean)? That way somebody with enough rep should be able to consider your proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a tag synonym, you need to have 1250 reputation (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

If you have enough reputation you will get an alternative to "Create tag synonym" on this page https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

On a tag page, clicking the synonym link, you'll see the rules behind creating tag synonyms:

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.