# Create Tag - reputation required - why 1250?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, tags

I've just been adding some tags to questions, but I find that the existing tags are not really sufficient (or else I don't know the existing tags well enough).

This led me to post this question about the [1,250 reputation requirement before a user is allowed to create new tags](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/how-to-create-tag-synonym-in-sharepoint-forum?rq=1).  I see a need for a new tag, but am unable to create one.  Is 1,250 reputation too high perhaps?  At the same time, I appreciate there is a need to prevent too many tags being created needlessly...a difficult balance to strike I guess.

My tag proposal is: "Information Lifecycle" or perhaps "Document Lifecycle".  There is a `Records Management` tag and an `Information Management` tag but neither exactly address the process of managing information lifecycle.  With GDPR legislation in the EU it is a valid area to address for Sharepoint Administrators since we need to manage sensitive data in accordance with the law.

Within the Sharepoint menus, there is an area called **Information Management Policy Settings** this area can be used to manage documents, content types, folders, data in other words.

[Here is a question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244709/delete-the-document-in-the-document-library-automatically-based-on-the-date-shar) which I think would benefit from an `Information Lifecycle` tag.  I've tagged it with Records Management, but don't feel that this exactly covers it.

Thanks for any comments and feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It "should be" lower, based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95497/180230) from Adam Lear.

However, looking into the matter, creating tag synonyms require 1250 rep and creating tags require 300 rep. So my guess is your looking at the wrong heading...

[image]

See [Privileges page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) for more details.