# Tag synonyms - how to submit a suggestion

Tags: support

I have insufficient total answer score on this tag, but to me it seems straightforward that AD and Active Directory are one and the same.  Yet I can't suggest that they be made synonyms of each other.

I read [this Answer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/how-to-create-tag-synonym-in-sharepoint-forum) but I still can't submit it, due to insufficient points on the AD or Active Directory tags.  The system probably doesn't work that well if nobody else has made the connection between these two tags yet.  Just putting it out there for discussion...

[image: AD and Active Directory synonym]

**Further observation** - the [a year in Moderation 2018](http://2018:%20a%20year%20in%20moderation) post shows only 4 Tag Synonyms were proposed in 2018 - not very many!  Are the experience requirements too strict?  Yet I do appreciate the other side of this, that SPSE wish to uphold the tag 'data quality'.

**Year 2020 update** - the year in Moderation 2019 post show 6 Tag Synonyms were proposed in 2019 - a 50% increase, woo-hoo!  Still nobody has marked AD and Active Directory as tag synonyms.  I realise it's not the most exciting topic to post about, but it's curious that it receives no attention.  I still can not even suggest the two tags as synonyms...

Comment: There are synonyms here that were [proposed nearly three years ago](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) that still only have a single vote, many from the past year that have no votes one way or the other.  I suspect that the common thread between small number of proposed synonyms and lack of votes is that most people don't care enough about tag usage to spend any time cleaning them up.

Comment: Thanks for commenting willman, I didn't know about that page, so I've performed my civic voting duty!  I think you've hit the nail on the head with the explanation.